# how to initialize an endpoint_t variable in minix3?

Tags: operating-system, initialization, driver, endpoint, minix

I have followed [this](http://wiki.minix3.org/doku.php?id=developersguide:newkernelcall) and [this](http://wiki.minix3.org/doku.php?id=developersguide:driverprogramming) to make a functional driver in minix3.

I am trying to initialize an endpoint_t variable in order to call my function but all i get is

> Request 0x700 to RS failed; specified endpoint is not alive (error 215)

I am initializing endpoint_t with

```
endpoint_t endpoint = _ENDPOINT_P(getpid());
```

So, how do I properly initialize a process endpoint in minix3?